# quickest way to to convert list of tuples to a series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Consider a list of tuples `lst`

```
lst = [('a', 10), ('b', 20)]
```

***question***
What is the quickest way to convert this to the series

```
i
a    10
b    20
Name: c, dtype: int64
```

***attempts***

```
pd.DataFrame(lst, list('ic')).set_index('i').c
```

This is inefficient.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: @Douglas Python 3

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Two possible downsides to `@Divakar's` `np.asarray(lst)` - it converts everything to string, requiring Pandas to convert them back.  And speed - making arrays is relatively expensive.

An alternative is to use the `zip(*)` idiom to 'transpose' the list:

```
In [65]: lst = [('a', 10), ('b', 20), ('j',1000)]
In [66]: zlst = list(zip(*lst))
In [67]: zlst
Out[67]: [('a', 'b', 'j'), (10, 20, 1000)]
In [68]: out = pd.Series(zlst[1], index = zlst[0])
In [69]: out
Out[69]: 
a      10
b      20
j    1000
dtype: int32
```

Note that my dtype is int, not object.

```
In [79]: out.values
Out[79]: array(['10', '20', '1000'], dtype=object)
```

So in the array case, Pandas doesn't convert the values back to integer; it leaves them as strings.

==============

My guess about timings is off - I don't have any feel for pandas Series creation times.  Also the sample is too small to do meaningful timings:

```
In [71]: %%timeit
    ...: out=pd.Series(dict(lst))
1000 loops, best of 3: 305 µs per loop
In [72]: %%timeit
    ...: arr=np.array(lst)
    ...: out = pd.Series(arr[:,1], index=arr[:,0])
10000 loops, best of 3: 198 µs per loop
In [73]: %%timeit
    ...: zlst = list(zip(*lst))
    ...: out = pd.Series(zlst[1], index=zlst[0])
    ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 275 µs per loop
```

Or forcing the integer interpretation

```
In [85]: %%timeit
    ...: arr=np.array(lst)
    ...: out = pd.Series(arr[:,1], index=arr[:,0], dtype=int)
    ...: 
    ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 253 µs per loop
```

Comment: I think you quicken it up with `np.array(list(zip(*lst)))`

Comment: Just tested on a larger dataset. This `zip` based solution looks pretty faster than all of the rest, at least `2x+`! @piRSquared You might want to change the accepted solution there :)

Comment: @Divakar I was planning on testing it. Thx for that.

Comment: Since `lst` is a list of tuples it could also be turned into a structured array, and the two fields fed to `pandas`.  Conceptually this might be cleaner, but not faster.

Comment: More idiomatic, in my opinion, use unpacking, i.e. `idx, vals = zip(*lst), pd.Series(vals, index=idx)`.

Answer (score 11):

The simplest way is pass your list of tuples as a dictionary:

```
>>> pd.Series(dict(lst))
a   10
b   20
dtype: int64
```

Comment: this was faster for me than using zip

Comment: Note this may not preserve order

Answer (score 3):

One approach with `NumPy` assuming regular length list -

```
arr = np.asarray(lst)
out = pd.Series(arr[:,1], index = arr[:,0])
```

Sample run -

```
In [147]: lst = [('a', 10), ('b', 20), ('j',1000)]

In [148]: arr = np.asarray(lst)

In [149]: pd.Series(arr[:,1], index = arr[:,0])
Out[149]: 
a      10
b      20
j    1000
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

use `pd.Series` with a dictionary comprehension

```
pd.Series({k: v for k, v in lst})

a    10
b    20
dtype: int64
```

Comment: ...or just `dict(lst)`