# Sort Pandas Series on data descending then on index alphabetically, elegantly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sorting, numpy

I'm looking for a smooth way to sort a pandas Series by data descending, followed by index ascending. I've been looking around in the docs and on Stackoverflow but couldn't find a straightforward way.

The Series has approximately 5000 entries and is the result of a tf-idf analysis with NLTK.

However, below I provide a very small sample of the data to illustrate the problem.

```
import pandas as pd

index = ['146tf150p', 'anytime', '645', 'blank', 'anything']
tfidf = [1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000, 0.932702, 1.000000]

tfidfmax = pd.Series(tfidf, index=index)
```

For now I'm just converting the Series to a DataFrame, resetting the index, doing the sort and then setting the index, but I feel this is a big detour.

```
frame = pd.DataFrame(tfidfmax , columns=['data']).reset_index().sort_values(['data','index'], ascending=[False, True]).set_index(['index'])
3.02 ms ± 102 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

I'm looking forward to your suggestions!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.lexsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html) for this:

```
res = tfidfmax[np.lexsort((tfidfmax.index, -tfidfmax.values))]

print(res)

# 146tf150p    1.000000
# 645          1.000000
# anything     1.000000
# anytime      1.000000
# blank        0.932702
# dtype: float64
```

Note the reverse order in the syntax: the above code first sorts by descending values, then by index ascending.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know this numpy feature. Tested the speed as well: %timeit tfidfmax[np.lexsort((tfidfmax.index, -tfidfmax.values))]. 211 µs ± 6.86 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

Answer (score 3):

Use function `sorted` by `zip` both `list`s create new `Series` by [zip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40851163):

```
index = ['146tf150p', 'anytime', '645', 'blank', 'anything']
tfidf = [1.000000, 1.000000, 2.000000, 0.932702, 2.000000]

a = list(zip(*sorted(zip(index, tfidf),key=lambda x:(-x[1],x[0]))))

#if input is Series
#a = list(zip(*sorted(zip(tfidfmax.index,tfidfmax),key=lambda x:(-x[1],x[0]))))
s = pd.Series(a[1], index=a[0])
print (s)
645          2.000000
anything     2.000000
146tf150p    1.000000
anytime      1.000000
blank        0.932702
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks! Good angle. Do you know if there is somehow a way to use sort_values and refer to the index? I.e. tfidf.sort_values(*reference to values*, *reference to index*, ascending=[False, True]). A bit like the lexsort but then within pandas.

Comment: @Steven Van Dorpe unfortunately not yet implemented.

Answer (score 1):

simple:

```
In [15]: pd.Series(tfidfmax.sort_values(ascending=False),index=tfidfmax.sort_index().index)
Out[15]: 
146tf150p    1.000000
645          1.000000
anything     1.000000
anytime      1.000000
blank        0.932702
dtype: float64
```

or faster way:

```
In [26]: pd.Series(-np.sort(-tfidfmax),index=np.sort(tfidfmax.index))
Out[26]: 
146tf150p    1.000000
645          1.000000
anything     1.000000
anytime      1.000000
blank        0.932702
dtype: float64

In [17]: %timeit tfidfmax[np.lexsort((tfidfmax.index, -tfidfmax.values))]
10000 loops, best of 3: 104 µs per loop

In [18]: %timeit pd.Series(tfidfmax.sort_values(ascending=False),index=tfidfmax.sort_index().index)
1000 loops, best of 3: 406 µs per loop

In [27]: %timeit pd.Series(-np.sort(-tfidfmax),index=np.sort(tfidfmax.index))
10000 loops, best of 3: 91.2 µs per loop
```

Comment: Although the fastest solution, but be careful, it is wrong. Try check my data from my answer.

Comment: @Steven Van Dorpe main problem is if change data like in my answer to `tfidf = [1.000000, 1.000000, 2.000000, 0.932702, 2.000000]` and compare your input with input of this answer there is difference. Because this answer sorting index and values separately.

Comment: I tried this answer and it doesn't work with more complicated data indeed. Thanks for pointing this out @jezrael !